# Java Http server Get Post to Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, http, server

I have a simple HTTP server written in Java. What I trying to achieve is that I have a javascript/ajax client there is able to get message from the server. The Java server I have is able to detect the connection made but the client unable to GET the message that is out print from the server.

There is a button in my client, upon clicking it the server message did not get thought but is able to send connection to the server. The client should display "Test Server" upon clicking the button

**Client**

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server**

```
public class JavaHttpServer {

  protected void start() {
    ServerSocket s;

    System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 80");
    try {

      s = new ServerSocket(80);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
    for (;;) {
      try {

        Socket remote = s.accept();

        System.out.println("Connection, sending data.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        remote.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

        String str = ".";
        while (!str.equals(""))
          str = in.readLine();

        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Server: Bot");

        out.println("");

        out.println("<H1>Test Server</H2>");
        out.flush();
        remote.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JavaHttpServer ws = new JavaHttpServer();
    ws.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser probably rejects the response because you miss the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header.
Try to add it like this:
out.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: Good point. Errors like this should also print an error message in the console of the browser's dev tools.

Comment: where should I add  out.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");?
I am not using java servlet, I have no reponse header to add to

Comment: You should add it in the server code, right after the line: out.println("Content-Type: text/html");

Comment: I rewrote a new server code with httpserver so that I can sent sendResponseHeaders. Now I am able to GET message from server .
But your answer worked too

Comment: Is there any example with a Node.js server?